# How to make oracle db supports md5 encryption?

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-security, md5

I have been developing a java web app that contains login function using spring security, md5 encryption, and Oracle as the db. Before using md5 encryption, my app worked fine. But after using it, my app doesn't wan't to redirect to the next page, always login error. 
I had been googling, it said that oracle didn't support md5 yet.

Here is the xml:

```
    <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
        users-by-username-query="
          SELECT username, password, 1 as enabled 
          FROM USER_ACCOUNT WHERE username=?"

        authorities-by-username-query="        
          SELECT u.username, ur.authority FROM USER_ACCOUNT u, USER_ROLES ur 
          where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?" 

           /> 
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

is there any way to make oracle db supports md5 ecryption?

Regards

Yunus

Comment: MD5 is not ecryption, it is hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EJP is right. MD5 is a cryptographic hash function, not an encryption algorithm. As far as encryption algorithms go I believe Oracle supports 3DES168 and AES with various key sizes (128, 192 and 256 bits).

For a login function you DEFINITELY want to use a hashing function and not encryption. Hashes are one-way data transforms and encryption is meant for two-way conversions (you can encrypt and decrypt the target data). That being said Oracle does support various hashing methods as outlined in their docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65700

SHA1 hash:
hashed_data := dbms_crypto.hash( original_data, dbms_crypto.HASH_SH1 );

MD5 hash:
hashed_data := dbms_crypto.hash( original_data, dbms_crypto.HASH_MD5 );

If you're looking to implement an authentication system in I'd recommend using SHA-1. You should also salt the passwords before you hash them. You can read an excellent article on password salting here: http://www.cubehouse.org/blog/2011/05/02/password-hashing-how-to-make-it-not-suck-a-basic-guide/

For added security use SHA-2 with a long bit length as attacks against SHA-1 are becoming aggressively efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your user's password.

update users set password = lower(DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5 (input => UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('topSecretPassword'))) where username = 'user';